# Using Log4j2.10 and slf4j-api 1.8 in OSGI/Eclipse

Tags: osgi, slf4j, log4j2, serviceloader

I am trying to use Log4j2.10 and slf4j-api 1.8 beta1 in my eclipse project.
I cannot get the binding to work,slf4j complains with:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
```

It worked with Log4j 2.9.1 and slf4j-api 1.7.24 which was using the StaticLoggerBinder mechanism which is no longer supported in slf4j 1.8

My eclipse plugin depends on

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.osgi,
org.apache.logging.log4j.api,
org.apache.logging.log4j.core,
org.apache.logging.log4j.slf4j-impl,
slf4j.api
```

The problem is that in the LoggerFactory (slf4j-api) the ServiceLoader.load(SLF4JServiceProvider.class) call returns any empty list, so the spi file of the org.apache.logging.log4j.slf4j-impl is not found or not loaded.

Is there anything I am missing to get this working?

Thanks in advance,

Rob

Comment: Ah ServiceLoader... You may need to look at http://aries.apache.org/modules/spi-fly.html

Comment: Thanks for replying,
I saw that one, but that means modifying the slf4j-api and log4j.slf4j-impl manifest files, not?

I would expect it would work with the standard dependencies.
Rob

Answer (score 2):

You can use `org.apache.logging.log4j: log4j-slf4j18-impl` for binding with `SLF4J 1.8.x`, as mentioned in this [official documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Log4j2 does is not yet compatible with slf4j-api version 1.8.x which now uses the ServiceLoader mechanism as enforced by JPMS/jigsaw/Java9 modules.